# Is $L(u) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( p(x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) + q(x)u$ still a linear operator for $p=p(x,u)$, $q=q(x,u)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-transformations

Let $\displaystyle L(u) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(p(x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) + q(x)u$, where $p(x)$, $q(x)$ are $C^{1}$ functions.

Regarding $L(u)$, I have to do two things:

1. Show that $L(u)$ is a linear operator - i.e., that $L(c_{1}u_{1}+c_{2}u_{2}) = c_{1}L(u_{1}) + c_{2}L(u_{2})$, which I was able to do successfully.
2. If we change either $p(x)$ to $p(x,u)$ or $q(x)$ to $q(x,u)$, is the resulting new $L(u)$ a linear operator?  I.e., are any of $\displaystyle L_{1}(u)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( p(x,u) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x }\right)+ q(x)u$, $\displaystyle L_{2}(u)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( p(x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x }\right)+ q(x,u)u$, or $\displaystyle L_{3}(u)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( p(x,u) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x }\right)+ q(x,u)u$ also linear?

The second part is what I require assistance with.

I would say that the answer is no, because we do not know if the functions $p$ or $q$ are linear in $u$, but I don't know if that's right.

I'm rather hoping that the solution to this part of the problem is something simple like that, because if you try to show linearity directly by the definition $L(c_{1}u_{1}+c_{2}u_{2})=c_{1}L(u_{1})+c_{2}L(u_{2})$, the algebra gets very messy very fast.

Is my intuition correct? And if so/if not, is there an easier way to show it than jumping headfirst into what essentially becomes the algebra problem from hell?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try $p(x,u)=u, q(x,u)=0$ as an easy starting example.

Comment: @πr8 but that would definitely be linear. So, you're saying that it will be linear, regardless of what $p(x,u)$ and $q(x,u)$ are?

Comment: @πr8 and an easy starting example isn't a proof, doesn't show me how I would go about proving it, because, like I said, when you try to prove it for arbitrary $p$ and $q$, the algebra gets disgusting. And if it is not linear, a counterexample is what I need.

Comment: For "generic" functions $p$ and $q$ the answer is clearly negative. The condition $L_i(\alpha u ) = \alpha L_i (u)$ should be violated under rather weak assumptions on $p$ and $q$...
If you are looking for necessary and sufficient conditions under which you still get linear operators, the answer might become much more complicated.

Comment: @Siminore, I am not looking for necessary and sufficient. I was asked "Suppose $p = p(x,u)$ and/or $q = q(x,u)$. Is $L(u)$ a linear operator?" That doesn't sound like being asked to find necessary and sufficient conditions to me. The way I interpreted it, I just need to find a $p$ or $q$ that's not linear in $u$...

Comment: @JessyCat It is probable, yes. But you should single out two explicit functions $p$ and $q$, and then show carefully that the corresponding operator is non-linear.

Comment: @JessyCat If $p=u,q=0$, then the operator is $Lu=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x }\right)$ - is this linear?

Comment: @πr8, is that $p(x,u) = u$ and $q(x,u)=0$?

Comment: @JessyCat Yes, I believe so.

Comment: @πr8 it just looks a little weird to me is all. Almost like it defeats the purpose of making $p$ and $q$ multivariate functions.

Comment: @JessyCat A counterexample is a counterexample either way - if you're looking to avoid disgusting algebra, I feel like this is preferable. You could try things like $p(x,u)=xu, q(x,u)=xu$, and so on, if you want.